# AChartEngine, getting values of plots on click

Tags: java, achartengine

I used achartengine for coding a simple time chart. What I want to do is get the values that are already plotted by clicking on the point on the graph, is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that  mChartView is your GraphicalView:

```
mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                  double[] xy = mChartView.toRealPoint(0);

                  if (seriesSelection == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(GraficoMensile.this, "No chart element was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                  } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            GraficoMensile.this,
                        "Chart element in series index " + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                            + " data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was clicked"
                            + " closest point value X=" + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y=" + seriesSelection.getValue()
                            + " clicked point value X=" + (float) xy[0] + ", Y=" + (float) xy[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                }
              });
```

source:
http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java